# Words of the same length in a language

Tags: formal-languages, terminology

Let $L\subseteq\Sigma^*$ be a language, where $\Sigma$ is a set, and let $n\in\mathbb N$.

I am wondering if there is some good terminology for

> $L\cap\Sigma^n$.

Of course I could say "the set of words in $L$ of length $n$" but maybe there is some special terminology like "level set of length", "grade", "homogeneous section" or I don't know what.... ?

Comment: Nope. No special terminology (to my knowledge) apart from "the set of words from $L$ with length $n$"

Comment: The closest thing I know is the concept of a _slice_ in parameterized complexity, which is explained e.g. [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/86409/what-is-a-slice-of-a-parameterized-problem-q-kappa). One could argue that using the normal coding length as a parameter the set $L \cap \Sigma^n$ is the $n$th slice of $L$.

Comment: Yes, some of the names that you mention are used. $\Sigma^*$ is the [free monoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_monoid) over the $\Sigma$. A free monoid is a graded monoid by the monoid homomorphism $d:\Sigma\to\mathbb{N}$, defined as $d(\Sigma^n)=\{n\}$. The elements of $\Sigma^n$ are called the *degree* $n$ elements.

Comment: @Watercrystal "slices" sounds good, if it's not used a lot maybe it should be used more. I'll accept it as an answer.

Comment: @plop thanks, would the set $L\cap\Sigma^n$ be a "grade" then?

Comment: That's a name that people use, yes. It would always need to be defined before using, but well.